# Pattern replacement syntax

Tags: influxdb, grafana

The documentation grafana on the use with InfluxDb ([Using InfluxDB in Grafana](http://docs.grafana.org/features/datasources/influxdb/#alias-patterns)), it is mentioned the possibility to use as alias pattern:

> You can also use [[tag_hostname]] pattern replacement syntax

[image]

How it works ?

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the part after `$tag_` with the name of your group by tag.

Here is an example from the [Grafana demo site](http://play.grafana.org/dashboard/db/influxdb-group-by-variable?panelId=1&fullscreen&edit&orgId=1):

[image]

An alternative syntax is to use the substitution syntax with `[[tag_tagname]]` in the `Alias By`field. For example, `Grouped by: [[tag_hostname]]`.

[image]

Comment: Your answer describes the functionality : `$tag_hostname = replaced with the value of the hostname tag` not the one requested in the question.

Comment: Updated my answer. It's just an alternative syntax.